# How do i return 2 objects back to async fetch function

Tags: javascript, python, flask

My Python function is invoked from the async `fetch` function like below:

```
 const [response,
        dailyTradeResponse,
        getRSIGaugeChartResponse ] = await Promise.all([
            fetch("/callback/getStock?data=" + Stock + "&period=" + Period + "&interval=" + Interval + "&chartselected=" + Chartselected),
            fetch("/callback/getDailyTradeInfo?data=" + Stock + "&period=" + Period + "&interval=" + Interval ),
            fetch("/callback/getRSIGaugeChart?data=" + Stock),
            fetch("/callback/getCompanyBalanceSheet?data=" + Stock)
 ]);
```

The Python function `/callback/getRSIGaugeChart` needs to return 2 objects: one is a `RSIGaugeChart` another one is `PandaDataFrame`, "df_BUY_Opportunity".

Code like below:

```
        print(df.to_string())
        df_BUY = df.loc[df['Signle'] == 'BUY']
        df_BUY_Opportunity = df_BUY.drop(['Close', 'Volume'], axis=1)

        def update_chart(trace, points, selector):
            index = points.point_inds[0]
            trace.value = df['RSI'][index]
            fig.layout.annotations[0].text = df['Status'][index]

        fig.update_geos(projection_type="natural earth")
        rsiGaugeChartJson = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

        return (rsiGaugeChartJson, df_BUY_Opportunity)
```

My question is:

How do I send two objects back to response of the async `fetch` function `fetch("/callback/getRSIGaugeChart?data=" + Stock)`

Can any Python guru give me some advice? Giving me an example is much appreciated.

Comment: You should return JSON.